# ¿Como puedo solucionar este error en symfony?

Tags: php, datatables, symfony, twig

Estoy intentando mostrar en una tabla los datos de una entidad de la base de datos con symfony y me aparece un error que no conosco y por tanto no se como arreglarlo. Esta entidad esta relacionada con otras tres y toma los datos de ellas, pero no logro que los cargue y me aparece esto :[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui les dejo el codigo de mi clase entity y del .HTML.TWIG, Muchas Gracias

Entidad:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\IncidenciasRepository")
 */
class Incidencias
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Trazas", inversedBy="incidencias", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $idTrazas;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\MedidasAdmin", inversedBy="incidencias", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $idMedidasAdmin;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\MedidasSeguridad", inversedBy="incidencias", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $idMedidasSeguridad;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getIdTrazas(): ?trazas
{
    return $this->idTrazas;
}

public function setIdTrazas(trazas $idTrazas): self
{
    $this->idTrazas = $idTrazas;

    return $this;
}

public function getIdMedidasAdmin(): ?medidasAdmin
{
    return $this->idMedidasAdmin;
}

public function setIdMedidasAdmin(medidasAdmin $idMedidasAdmin): self
{
    $this->idMedidasAdmin = $idMedidasAdmin;

    return $this;
}

public function getIdMedidasSeguridad(): ?medidasSeguridad
{
    return $this->idMedidasSeguridad;
}

public function setIdMedidasSeguridad(medidasSeguridad $idMedidasSeguridad): self
{
    $this->idMedidasSeguridad = $idMedidasSeguridad;

    return $this;
}

}
```

Este es el .HTML.TWIG:

```
{% extends 'default/Plantilla.html.twig' %}
{% block subtitle %}<h1>Incidencias de Seguridad Informática</h1>{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<br/>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Traza</th>
            <th>Medida de Seguridad Informática</th>
            <th>Medida Administrativa</th>
            <th width="185px">Gestionar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for incidencia in incidencias %}
        <tr onmouseover="$(this).children('.columnAction').show();" onmouseout="$(this).children('.columnAction').hide();">
            <td>{{ incidencia.idTraza }}</td>
            <td>{{ incidencia.idMedidaAdmin }}</td>
            <td>{{ incidencia.idMedidaSeguridad }}</td>
            <td width="185px"  class="columnAction">

                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ path('incidencias_show', {'id': incidencia.id}) }}" id="botonShow"><i class="fa fa-eye" ></i></a>
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ path('incidencias_edit', {'id': incidencia.id}) }}" id="botonEdit"><i class="fa fa-edit" ></i></a>
                {{ include('incidencias/_delete_form.html.twig') }}

            </td>
        </tr>
    {% else %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">No existen datos registrados</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ path('incidencias_new') }}" id="botonAñadir"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" ></i>  Añadir</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: te falta una s... idTrazas

Comment: @Yoelvis no te preocupes por la publicación, que esté cerrada no te va a afectar negativamente (de hecho tiene votos positivos y una respuesta aceptada con votos positivos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El atributo del objeto es idTrazas, no idTraza, recuerda que cuando llamas a los atributos de un objeto, debes llamarlo por su nombre completo. El validador de Symfony toma el nombre (en este caso, idTrazas) y le antepone el Get para utilizar dicha función